# How to access Form components from cpp file

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am working with windows form application. I am having one form i.e Form1.h. In this form I have one pictureBox named pictureBox1. And I have one main.cpp file in which I want to access pictureBox1 of the Form1.h and display some Image from main.cpp file.

For doing this I am using this code

main.cpp

```
#include "Form1.h"
    using namespace PUMA_LED_TESTER;

Form1^ form1=gcnew Form1; 

form1->pictureBox1->Image =bmp;
```

But this code is giving error

```
error C3145: 'form1' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'PUMA_LED_TESTER::Form1 ^'
          may not declare a global or static variable, or a member of a native type that refers to objects in the gc heap
```

I don't know why this error is coming. Can any body please tell me the solution for this error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You'll have to put code inside a method.  With the additional requirement that a variable that's a reference to a managed type needs to go inside a ref class.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for reply. I have put this code in a simple method. Is it compulsory to make a ref class to use this code? Or if there is other way then please tell me.